# Is $y\left( x\right) =\dfrac {d^{2}x} {dt^2}|_{t=1}$ a linear functional for vector space of polynomials?

Tags: vector-spaces, derivatives

Let $P$ be the set of all polynomials, with complex coefficients, in a variable $t$. For $x$ in $P$ the function $y$ is defined by 
$y\left( x\right) =\dfrac {d^{2}x} {dt^2}|_{t=1}$
Is $y$ a linear functional?
Now I am aware of $y$ being a scalar valued function and the defining property of a linear functional is 
$$y\left( \alpha _{1}x_{1}+\alpha_{2}x_{2}\right) =\alpha _{1}y\left( x_{1}\right) +\alpha _{2}y\left( x_{2}\right)$$
It is the actual definition of $y$ which I am confused about.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are Latex expression not showing up correctly ?

Comment: Put math inside dollar ($) signs. Please make sure my edit didn't introduce errors.

Comment: Do you mean $dt^2$ instead of $dt^{-2}$?

Comment: As it stands now it is correct thanks for your help and the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that $x(t)$ is a polynomial in the variable $t$. We have the map $y: x(t)\mapsto x''(1)$. The map takes a polynomial $x$ and returns a scalar value, the value given by the second derivative of $x$ evaluated at $t=1$. In order to see why this is linear, you have to check three things:

- Differentiation is linear: $(\alpha \, x_1(t)+\beta\, x_2(t))'=\alpha x_1'(t)+\beta x_2'(t)$.
- "Plugging in $t=a$" (here $a$ is fixed) is linear: $\big(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2\big)|_{t=a}=\alpha\big(x_1\big)|_{t=a}+\beta\big(x_2\big)|_{t=a}.$
- The composition of two linear maps is itself linear.

Comment: Thanks buddy u made it really simple i thought there might have been more to t = 1 but obviously not.